# How to login after activating account?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I can't login even my code is working. Like if the activated=1 it will login, otherwise it will not login. The row activated in my table is already set to 1 which means that it is activated already. But I can't login. It always output the activated=0, which is Login failed! Please click the link on your email address!

```
public function index()
{
    $Username=$this->input->post("username");
    $Password=$this->input->post("password");

    $this->form_validation->set_rules("username", "username", "trim|required");
    $this->form_validation->set_rules("password", "password", "trim|required");

    $this->db->where('Username', $this->input->post('username'));
    $this->db->where('Password', $this->input->post('password'));       
    $this->db->select('activated');
    $que=$this->db->get('tblaccount');

    if ($this->form_validation->run()==FALSE)
    {
        $this->load->view('login_view');
    }
    else
    {
        $account=$this->account_model->get_user($Username, sha1($Password));
        if (count($account)>0)
        {
            if ($que->row('activated')==1)
            {
                $sess_data=array('login'=>TRUE, 'picture'=>$account[0]->Picture, 'firstname'=>$account[0]->First_Name, 'lastname'=>$account[0]->Last_Name, 'id'=>$account[0]->AID, 'position'=>$account[0]->Position, 'department'=>$account[0]->Department);
                $this->session->set_userdata($sess_data);

                if ($_SESSION['position']=="Professor")
                {
                    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Welcome to attendance monitoring system, $_SESSION[firstname] $_SESSION[lastname]!');window.location='".base_url("index.php/main")."';</script>";
                }
                else if ($_SESSION['position']=="Department Chair")
                {
                    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Welcome to attendance monitoring system, $_SESSION[firstname] $_SESSION[lastname]!');window.location='".base_url("index.php/report")."';</script>";
                }
                else if ($_SESSION['position']=="OSA Faculty"||"Guidance Faculty")
                {
                    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Welcome to attendance monitoring system, $_SESSION[firstname] $_SESSION[lastname]!');window.location='".base_url("index.php/faculty")."';</script>";
                }
            }
            else if ($que->row('activated')==0)
            {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', '<div class="alert alert-danger text-center">Login failed! Please click the link on your email address!</div>');
                redirect('login');
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', '<div class="alert alert-danger text-center">Wrong Username or Password!</div>');
            redirect('login');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not do a `var_dump($que)` after the line containing `$que=$this->db->get('tblaccount');`? That way you can see what your query returns, and possibly why your code reacts the way it does. See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php

Comment: What is the value of `activated` in the database for the account you're trying to log into? If it's `0` the error will likely reside in the code that activates an account. Looks like the possible issue to me.

Comment: The value of activated in the database for the account is 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand one part of your code.
Actually, you firstly put `$this->db->where('Password', $this->input->post('password'));`, and then `$account=$this->account_model->get_user($Username, sha1($Password));`

You should correct the first one adding : `sha1($this->input->post('password'))`, cause I think that actually your request returns an empty row, that's why the last condition is used since you did not provide an else condition, that is bad practice in PHP.
Let me know !

Comment: I got an idea from your answer, now it is working. Thanks to you! What I did is I remove the `$this->db->where('Username',$this->input->post('username'));` and `$this->db->where('Password',$this->input->post('password'));`